# How do I combine two arrays in PHP based on a common key?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to join two associative arrays together based on an `entry_id` key. Both arrays come from individual database resources, the first stores entry titles, the second stores entry authors, the key=>value pairs are as follows:

```
array (
    'entry_id' => 1,
    'title' => 'Test Entry'
)   

array (
    'entry_id' => 1,
    'author_id' => 2
```

I'm trying to achieve an array structure like:

```
array (
    'entry_id' => 1,
    'author_id' => 2,
    'title' => 'Test Entry'
)
```

Currently, I've solved the problem by looping through each array and formatting the array the way I want, but I think this is a bit of a memory hog.

```
$entriesArray = array();
foreach ($entryNames as $names) {
    foreach ($entryAuthors as $authors) {
        if ($names['entry_id'] === $authors['entry_id']) {
            $entriesArray[] = array(
                'id' => $names['entry_id'],
                'title' => $names['title'],
                'author_id' => $authors['author_id']
            );                          
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to know is there an easier, less memory intensive method of doing this?

Comment: If the solution is a sql one, shouldn't this page be tagged differently and have some db table details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rearranged some of my code to allow for a single SQL query, which looks like:

```
$sql = sprintf('SELECT DISTINCT wd.field_id_5, wd.entry_id, mb.email, mb.screen_name 
            FROM `exp_weblog_data` wd
            INNER JOIN `exp_weblog_titles` wt
            ON wt.entry_id=wd.entry_id
            INNER JOIN `exp_members` mb
            ON mb.member_id=wt.author_id
            WHERE mb.member_id IN ("%s")
            AND wd.entry_id IN ("%s")',
            join('","', array_unique($authors)),
            join('","', array_unique($ids))
);
```

This solves my problem quite nicely, even though I'm making another SQL call. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you can do a JOIN in the SQL used to retrieve the information from the database rather than fetching the data in multiple queries? It would be much faster and neater to do it at the database level.

Depending on your database structure you may want to use something similar to

```
SELECT entry_id, title, author_id
FROM exp_weblog_data
INNER JOIN exp_weblog_titles
ON exp_weblog_data.entry_id = exp_weblog_titles.entry_id
WHERE field_id_53 = "%s" AND WHERE entry_id IN ("%s")
```

[Wikipedia has a bit on each type of join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Otherwise the best option may be to restructure the first array so that it is a map of the entry_id to the title

So:

```
array(
    array(
       'entry_id' => 1,
       'title' => 'Test Entry 1',
    ),
    array(
       'entry_id' => 3,
       'title' => 'Test Entry 2',
    ),
)
```

Would become:

```
array(
    1 => 'Test Entry 1',
    3 => 'Test Entry 2',
)
```

Which would mean the code required to merge the arrays is simplified to this:

```
$entriesArray = array();
foreach ($entryAuthors as $authors) {
    $entriesArray[] = array(
        'id' => $authors['entry_id'],
        'title' => $entryNames[$authors['entry_id']],
        'author_id' => $authors['author_id']
    );                           
}
```

Comment: Its an expression engine website, so I'm not entirely sure, my SQL queries are:

    SELECT entry_id, field_id_5 AS title_ie FROM exp_weblog_data WHERE field_id_53 = "%s"

and:

    SELECT entry_id, title, author_id FROM exp_weblog_titles WHERE entry_id IN ("%s")

There is a distinct WHERE clauses in each query and my SQL knowledge is limited, can I combine both queries into one?

Comment: -1 How much are you sure that `It would be much faster and neater to do it at the database level.` Don't you think connecting to database, join two tables or more and returning the result would be much slower. I strongly recommend you reading 'MySQL High Performance' book to get grasp of database and indexing. Joining two tables at application level is faster beside that there would much more chance that MySQL fetch the result faster, because each query will be fetched by its PRIMARY KEY that is fast. It would much more ideal if you want to cache it on the web application.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment on Yacoby's post, will this SQL not give the output you are after?

```
SELECT exp_weblog_data.entry_id, exp_weblog_data.field_id_5 AS title_ie, exp_weblog_titles.author_id 
FROM exp_weblog_data LEFT JOIN exp_weblog_titles 
ON exp_weblog_data.entry_id = exp_weblog_titles.entry_id 
WHERE exp_weblog_data.field_id_53 = "%S"
```

Every entry in exp_weblog_data where field_id_53 = "%S" will be joined with any matching authors in exp_weblog_titles, if a an entry has more than one author, two or more rows will be returned.

Answer (score -2):

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: If you read the question it becomes clear that that isn't what is wanted. I think the example arrays shown are single elements of a larger array.

Comment: array_merge will only append the second array to the first, I want to join them by `entry_id` which is a unique key in both arrays